# Laravel 7: change db connection settings into env file not being reflected

Tags: php, database, laravel, laravel-7

I'm testing a laravel application on different SQL Server versions but changes to .env file seems not being reflected.

I've cleared settings several times with

```
php artisan clear-compiled 
composer dump-autoload
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan config:clear
php artisan optimize
```

But when I run `php artisan migrate` nothing happens on the newly configured instance. If a take offline the db on the old instance then the migration fails with the following error:

```
Illuminate\Database\QueryException

SQLSTATE[28000]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Login failed for user 'sa'. (SQL: select * from sysobjects where type = 'U' and name = migrations)

at C:\Laravel\htdocs\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:671
667|         // If an exception occurs when attempting to run a query, we'll format the error
668|         // message to include the bindings with SQL, which will make this exception a
669|         // lot more helpful to the developer instead of just the database's errors.
670|         catch (Exception $e) {
> 671|             throw new QueryException(
672|                 $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
673|             );
674|         }
675|

1   C:\Laravel\htdocs\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connectors\Connector.php:70
  PDOException::("SQLSTATE[28000]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Login failed for user 'sa'.")

2   C:\Laravel\htdocs\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connectors\Connector.php:70
  PDO::__construct("sqlsrv:Server=.\DEV19,1433;Database=Opera6Laravel", "sa", "test", [])
```

In this error the connection string targets the correct instance (`DEV19`) but it won't work untile I take back online the db on the old instance (`EXP17`), so this make me think that the old instance is still being targeted despite the connection string shown in the error.

Finally, I've opened SQL Profiler tool and had confirmation that the script is still targeting the old instance.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Just to be sure that you did not break the link to the `.env` file: If you check the `config/database.php` config, can you tell us what the content of this file is? There should be a couple of referencess to the `env()` function, but sometimes people remove these and put the config in there directly.

Comment: @RobBiermann here it is: https://pastebin.com/Xq8NbB3K . The only thing changed should be that I added a second connection.

Comment: Hmm, everything looks fine to me. I'm not 100% sure what a valid next step would be. I've had issues in the past with microsoft drivers. Do you setup a ODBC connection like in this article? https://support.office.com/en-us/article/administer-odbc-data-sources-b19f856b-5b9b-48c9-8b93-07484bfab5a7 Im affraid I cannot help further if this is not the issue.

Comment: @RobBiermann no ODBCs...thanks anyway for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. In my case I use Homestead and I try to run the artisan migrate outside from vagrant. So the solution is ssh to your host where the site is hosted and try again the php artisan migrate command there.